# Docker container start issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-daemon

I am trying to start docker containers, Seems like it has failed. After Analyzing DockerD logs.

```
ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar 13 21:37:58 ubuntu-nuc2 dockerd[692]: time="2020-03-13T21:37:58.277230495Z" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Mar 13 21:37:58 ubuntu-nuc2 dockerd[692]: time="2020-03-13T21:37:58.277625568Z" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
Mar 13 21:37:58 ubuntu-nuc2 dockerd[692]: time="2020-03-13T21:37:58.364681832Z" level=error msg="54dd3a9bfcbcbcdddcc82350e8045985d8c8495ac465e7e335c3a91b75bdf30b cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Mar 13 21:37:58 ubuntu-nuc2 dockerd[692]: time="2020-03-13T21:37:58.364824367Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.25/containers/54dd3a9bfcbcbcdddcc82350e8045985d8c8495ac465e7e335c3a91b75bdf30b/start returned error: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:449: container init caused \\\"rootfs_linux.go:109: jailing process inside rootfs caused \\\\\\\"pivot_root invalid argument\\\\\\\"\\\"\": unknown"
Mar 13 21:37:59 ubuntu-nuc2 dockerd[692]: time="2020-03-13T21:37:59.159258456Z" level=error msg="8292a9a1eb9fccfe8848c57f3aaaf2c52c557c5b55b606112cdf66148fbba6d7 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Mar 13 21:37:59 ubuntu-nuc2 dockerd[692]: time="2020-03-13T21:37:59.159376298Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.25/containers/8292a9a1eb9fccfe8848c57f3aaaf2c52c557c5b55b606112cdf66148fbba6d7/start returned error: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown"
Mar 13 22:14:22 ubuntu-nuc2 dockerd[692]: time="2020-03-13T22:14:22.094213684Z" level=error msg="Error setting up exec command in container rwo_gluster-server_1: Container 54dd3a9bfcbcbcdddcc82350e8045985d8c8495ac465e7e335c3a91b75bdf30b is not running"
-- Reboot --
Mar 13 22:24:23 ubuntu-nuc2 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
```

I went through several threads for help and got this.

```
export DOCKER_RAMDISK=true
```

But not able to figure out what is happening, Why Containers failed due to pivot_root error?

Docker-compose.yml:

```
gluster-server:
    image: edge/glusterfs-rest:7
    entrypoint: dumb-init glusterd --no-daemon --pid-file=/var/run/glusterd.pid
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    ipc: host
    network_mode: host
    # pid: host
    userns_mode: host
    volumes:
      - gluster_database_vol:/var/lib/glusterd
      - docker_pid_vol:/var/run
      - /mnt:/mnt:shared
      - /dev:/dev
      - /opt:/opt
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - /var/log/glusterfs:/var/log/glusterfs:shared
      - /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
    depends_on:
      - app-docker
      - gluster-rest
      - gluster-security-enabler
```

Comment: Your `docker-compose.yml` file and/or `dockerfile` would be helpful.